# Getting Data from SQL Server to populate in DataGrid in C# WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to get the data from my database to populate in my DataGrid in my WPF application. I have my database connected to to VisualStudio 2012 and have a .dml file for it. The Data should load when you click on the "Firework Catalog" button on the main window.

To my knowledge I have all necessary references and nothing is erroring out when I build and debug. Also the new Window opens, and presents the grid, but no data. Here is some code

**FireworkCatalog.xaml**

```
    <DataGrid Name="FireworkCatalogGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="236" Width="508" SelectionChanged="FireworkCatalogGrid_Window_Loaded" Background="#FF7C7878" BorderBrush="#FFDC3B18">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Path=Type}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Class" Binding="{Binding Path=Class}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="description" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}"/>

       </DataGrid.Columns>
```

---

**FireworkCatalog.xaml.cs**

```
  private void FireworkCatalogGrid_Window_Loaded(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        FireworkDataDataContext data = new FireworkDataDataContext();
        List <fireworkType> fireworks = (from f in data.fireworkTypes
                                         select f) .ToList();
        FireworkCatalogGrid.ItemsSource = fireworks;
    }
```

---

**MainScreen.xaml.cs**

```
 private void FwkCatalog_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
       FireworkCatalog catalog = new FireworkCatalog();
       catalog.ShowDialog();
  }
```

---

Here is some of the auto generated code when using the Linq to SQL for the database so you can see the table name and the columns thus far.

**FireworkData.designer.cs**

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.fireworkType")]
public partial class fireworkType
{

    private string _Type;

    private string _Class;

    private string _Name;

    private string _Description;

    public fireworkType()
    {
    }
    }
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or any other ideas on how to get the data from my SQL Server to my WPF.

---

**EDIT.**

Here is another set of code to see how each column's data can be asscessed

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Type", DbType="VarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Type;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Type != value))
            {
                this._Type = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `fireworkType` type have any public properties?  You'll need to expose `Type`, `Class`, `Name`, and `Description` as public properties in order for the binding to be able to pick up the values.

```
private string _Type;
public string Type
{
    get { return _Type; }        
}
```

As a separate issue, if you want these to be editable you'll need to add setters.  If you want to update these values and have them display automatically in the grid, you'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: each column's value is already have a public property set to them, see in the above edit.